# Continue Button not working in magento 1.9 Installation

Tags: magento

when I was installing Magento 1.9.2 in godaddy, the 'continue' button in 'License Agreement' page not working.   pls anyone help me to resolve this issue.  reply is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Shikha

Comment: See This [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Installation-Continue-button-does-not-work-under-license/td-p/4611).

Comment: Check your file permission and then try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

to fix the permissions enter the ssh commands:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod +x mage
```